# SQL Server stored procedure coming up empty

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, data-retrieval

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that is not returning any data when I plug in my parameter...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.EncumBugSearch 
@year datetime
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select *
From dbo.BudgetEncumberedTbl as bet
where year(dateadd(month,-3,bet.be_dateposted)) = @year
order by be_dateposted desc

END
GO
```

This returns nothing, however, when I plug in a number for the parameter (i.e. 2011) then I get the correct results... any ideas?

Comment: You say *SQL* (Structured Query Language - a vendor-independent language) but you really mean **SQL Server** (Microsoft's relational database product) - right?

Comment: How do you pass the parameter to stored procedure?

Comment: Yes SQL Server (I apologize) and I pass it through a user selected Item on my asp.net page.

Comment: @year as a datetime isn't in the same format as the year  in your where clause....  In other words 1/1/2012 <> year(dateadd(month-3)bet.be_Dateposted) which would likley be 2012. so 1/1/2012 <> 2012.  wouldn't you need to year(@year)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your parameter is a datetime, when [it should be an int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx).